# Linear algebra - how to avoid the mess

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix, and assume $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ is invertible

$X = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2}
\end{pmatrix}$

Then how do I find $(0,1,0) (X^{T}X)^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$
Without having to calculate everything? I know that I only end up with just 1 entry, but which one is it ? Any hints is appreciated

Comment: $X^TX$ may not be invertible, so we cannot compute this.

Comment: Yes - how many elements are in the $\cdots$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I changed it so that we may assume it is invertible

Comment: @FShrike n elements

Comment: But this means complicated conditions on the coefficients $x_i$, so that you don't know whether your result applies to it or not.

Comment: If $X \in K^{3 \times n}$, then $X^T \in K^{n \times 3}$ and $X^TX \in K^{n \times n}$, with the inverse of that being from the same space. You can only multiply that with the given vectors if $n=3$.

Comment: Since $X^TX$ is a tiny $3\times 3$ matrix, it feels like an enormous waste of time to develop a complicated algebraic expression for its inverse.  Just invert it and extract the $(2,3)$ component.

Answer (score 1):

$$
X^TX=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \cr  1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr  0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 1 \cr  1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is not invertible.

Comment: True, but what if we assume it is invertible.

Comment: Then we obtain something like $1+x_1^2+x_2^2$ in the $3\times 3$-case.

Comment: I will change notation a bit of $X$ just for convenience

Comment: Sorry I gave you the transpose in the original question, now it should be fixed.......